# What actually starts the command queue execution?

Tags: opencl

Does `clFinish` function trigger the command queue execution?
Or `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel`?

I need to know it mostly to know when to start the time measurements.

Answer (score 1):

Check this stackoverflow answer to understand this in a better way:

[LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12509587/opencl-kernel-execution-does-not-start-until-clfinish-or-clwaitforevents-is-call)

Answer (score 0):

I believe `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel` *may* start command queue execution, but this is implementation defined. If you want to guarantee that commands start running (in the background), call `clFlush`. `clFinish` implies `clFlush` but additionally waits for all the queued kernels to *complete* execution.